Within IMPORTRANGE, how do I edit the formula so that just the Sheet portion of the range_string can be cell referenced?
("URL","11/14/24!F28") - for example
Would like to be able to change the 11/14/24 to be whatever date I am placing in a reference cell because that is how the sheets are named in the file I am pulling from.

The feature that you are looking for is text concatenation. In Google Sheets formulas, you might use the CONCATENATE function and the concatenate operator (&).
Example
Assuming that A1 has the sheet name as a text value:
=IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet ID or URL", A1&"!F28"

In case A1 includes a date value, first, we should convert it to a text value:
=IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet ID or URL", TEXT(A1,"MM/dd/yyyy")&"!F28"


That did it! Wasn't working at first then I simply ensured cell was text based and that was it. Thank you so much!
